# Django OAuth Toolkit

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use oauth2 authentication using django oauth toolkit. I got the following exception : 
Could not import 'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication' for API setting 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'

My settings.py file looks like :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rest_framework',
'adaccounts',
'corsheaders',
'clients',
'Gen42Backend',
'djcelery',
'oauth2_provider'

 )

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
 )
 }
```

Comment: Which version of oauth toolkit and django are you using

Comment: django 1.11.1 and django-oauth-toolkit 1.0.0

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone has the same problem.

Replace:

```
oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication
```

With:

```
oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication
```

Comment: Also remember to import as from oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework import